# How to add UITabBar with one UITabbarItem work as button?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

[image: I want something like looking in image, I want to do this in tabbar application or mainstoryboard. This i did normal single view based application with tabbar item.]

I want something like looking in image, I want to do this in tabbar application or mainstoryboard. This i did normal single view based application with tabbar item.

I try following code also, in this when i click tabbar items particular viewcontroller opens. But i want on click of third tabbar item it should show UIActionSheet not third viewcontroller. How i can achieve this.

```
FisrtTabViewController  *first = [[FisrtTabViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FisrtTabViewController" bundle:nil];
[first.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myarea_selected.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myarea.png"]];

UINavigationController *tabItem1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: first];    

SecconTabViewController  *second = [[SecconTabViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecconTabViewController" bundle:nil];

[ second.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"areaconv_selected.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"areaconv.png"]];

ThirdTabViewController  *third = [[ThirdTabViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdTabViewController" bundle:nil];
[ third.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"share_selected.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"share.png"]];

tabbar1.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:tabItem1,second,third,nil];

[[UITabBar appearance]setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar.png"]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_selected.png"]];

tabbar1.modalTransitionStyle =UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

[self presentViewController:tabbar1 animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What code have you tried and what did it do wrong?

Comment: put relevant code here.. create your third viewcontroller in your third TabBarItem Action method as you putted in other 2 action of your tabItems